# What is the opposite of "skyrocket"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, antonyms

I recently came across a situation where something was decreasing rapidly. My friend was led to say:

> The price of fuel has really **skyrocketed downwards** lately.

Something about this statement sounded wrong. Surely a *skyrocket* must always go *up*, by definition.

What would be a more suitable word or phrase to describe something that is decreasing rapidly?

Comment: General Reference. [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/skyrocket): *plummet*; [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skyrocket): *nose-dive, plummet, plunge*.

Comment: Do people agree that "skyrocketing downwards" is not correct? What about merely _rocketing_ downwards"?

Comment: "Skyrocketed downwards" is awkward, but understandable. Whether it's "correct" or not depends on what you mean by "correct". Same thing for "rocketing downwards", mostly because we don't usually use the verb form like that.

Comment: "Skyyyrockets in flight.  Afternoon delight!"

Comment: Free fall - "The price of fuel is in a full on free fall lately."

Comment: "groundrocketed"?

Comment: These are all excellent answers.

Comment: Freefall - Rapid uncontrolled decline
  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/free+fall
All the other answers are good, but somehow 'freefall' goes the best with 'skyrocket' with reference to earth's gravitational force. "One defies gravity, the other one enjoys/succumbs to it."

Answer (score 114, accepted):

[*Plummeted*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/plummet)?

> 1. Fall or drop straight down at high speed.
> 2. Decrease rapidly in value or amount.

Comment: As Joost mentioned, "plummeted" is more applicable as the context is about finance and pricing with respect to your question.

Comment: I've loved this word ever since the immortal lines "Now witness their attempts to fly from tree to tree. Notice they do not so much fly as plummet." ([Monty Python, Flying Sheep](http://youtu.be/Vkw2DdoskPY?t=1m3s))

Answer (score 76):

> The price of fuel has **taken a nose-dive**.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nosedive):

> *nose-dive*
>
> 1 : a downward nose-first plunge of a flying object (such as an airplane)
>
> 2 : a sudden extreme drop
> *stock prices took a nosedive*

Comment: Or just "nose-dived".

Comment: +1 for being the closest to the flying metaphor used by skyrocket.

Answer (score 28):

*Tanked* is likely an option.

> The price of fuel has tanked in recent weeks.

Comment: *Tanked* is a great word to use if you're writing a catchy headline for this event, because it creates a fuel-related pun.

Comment: Headline: "The price of fuel tanks" Reader:"The price of fuel tanks does WHAT?!?!"

Comment: Any attention to a headline is good attention. :)

Answer (score 21):

I'm not sure there is a direct equivalent but the normal phrase used in that situation is

> The price of fuel has **plummeted** recently.

or

> The price of fuel has **gone through the floor** lately.

Comment: I see "plummet" way more often.

Answer (score 14):

*Crashed* is another contender, and if you're looking for something a little more idiomatic you could say it's *dropped like a stone*.

Comment: And when it is irretrievable, *crashed and burned*.

Answer (score 14):

I'd be perfectly comfortable with *plunged*, e.g.

> The price at the pump has plunged since OPEC met.

Answer (score 2):

In keeping with the space-themed metaphor, the opposite of *skyrocketed* would be **cratered**.  However, that suggests that the fall is catastrophic and perhaps unrecoverable, which may not be the connotation you are looking for if you are talking about the price of fuel.

Answer (score 0):

Lead balloon is nice but does not really work as an adjective.  *Lead Balloned* does not quite roll off the tongue.